# In SceneKIT how do I add a material to my SCNNode() that has SCNPlane() geometry?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

I am trying to create a 3d model that is moving above a 2d background. I read somewhere else that in order to do that I need to create a `SCNNode()` with `SCNPlane()` geometry and use my backgroundimage as the material of the `SCNPlane()`. However I have no clue how to add materials to a geometry structure, can you help me?

So far this is my code:

```
let background = SCNNode()
background.geometry = SCNPlane()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add your texture image to your assets catalogue, say "Background.jpg", to **Assets.xcassets**

Then

```
let background = SCNNode()
background.geometry = SCNPlane.init(width: 100, height: 100) // better set its size
background.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = "Background.jpg"
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(background)
```